# MinGW tar compression problem

Tags: windows, tar, mingw

I am unable to get the **Mingw tar** to work with compress files. It does not filter through the proper compression utility. However, tar will work if I manually uncompress the file first. I have tried in both the **MSYS shell** and Windows **cmd**. Has anyone had this problem or is it a MinGW bug?

For example, **this does not work**:

```
C:\Users\home\Desktop>tar -tzf wdiff-0.5.tar.gz
tar: Cannot use compressed or remote archives
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

C:\Users\home\Desktop>tar -t -Zgzip -f wdiff-0.5.tar.gz
tar: Cannot use compressed or remote archives
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

C:\Users\home\Desktop>tar -tf wdiff-0.5.tar.gz
tar: Hmm, this doesn't look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next file header
tar: Only read 6732 bytes from archive wdiff-0.5.tar.gz
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

However, **this works:**

```
gzip -d wdiff-0.5.tar.gz
tar -tf wdiff-0.5.tar
```

Comment: MinGW tar -tvzf "file" seems to be working now... just needed another reboot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

some tar implementations do not include compressing/decompressing. thats just .. how they are configured / compiled / linked. i would not describe that as a bug.

you could combine the 2 steps involved in untarring a compressed tarball with something like this:

```
 % zcat in.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

or

```
 % zcat in.tar.gz | tar tf -
```

(zcat is usually just aliased to 'gzip -cd')

Comment: that's what this looks like to me, too.  @Shiftbit, you should check the documentation for your *tar* to see if there are any notes about stuff that isn't compiled into the MinGW version.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. I used `tar` from cygwin to use `-z` switch in tar under Windows to resolve the issue.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://superuser.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: The question is how to run "C:\Users\home\Desktop>c:\cygwin\bin\tar -tzf wdiff-0.5.tar.gz" without errors. The answer is to use tar from cygwin, i.e. to run smth like ""C:\Users\home\Desktop>c:\cygwin\bin\tar -tzf wdiff-0.5.tar.gz""

Comment: "I also have this problem" is a very strong indicator for a wrong use of answers. I slightly edited your answer to point out you actually have an answer to the question, and are not also searching for help.